# How do I set this list of numbers in my runner to an ArrayList in the constructor?

Tags: java

I've been struggling with this for a while now. I know that I can instantiate a String to an ArrayList in the constructo but I don't know how I would instantiate a group of ints to a ArrayList from the runner without doing it all manully using list.add(number) over and over again.

```
void setup() { //My runner
  NumAnalyzer test = new NumAnalyzer("5 12 9 6 1 4 8 6");

  out.println("even count = "+test.countEvens());
  out.println("odd count = "+test.countOdds());
  out.println("perfect count = "+test.countPerfects()+"\n\n\n");


  //add more test cases
}




import java.util.ArrayList;    
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class NumAnalyzer{
  private ArrayList<Number> list;

  public NumAnalyzer(String word){
    list = new ArrayList<Number>(); //This instantiates it as a String but I want it to instantiate it as a list of integers. 
  }


  public int countOdds(){ //counting odds
      int oddCount=0;
      for(int x=0; x<list.size(); x++){
        if(list.get(x)%2 != 0){
          oddCount++;
        }
      }
      return oddCount;
  }

  public int countEvens(){ //counting evens
      int evenCount=0;
     for(Number num : list){
        if(list.get(num)%2 == 0){
           evenCount++;
        }
      }
      return evenCount;
  }

  public int countPerfects() {
     int perfectCount=0;
     for(int x=0; x<list.size(); x++){

       int mult=2, factorsum=0; //gets the sum of the multiples
       while(list.get(x) != mult){
         if(list.get(x)%mult == 0){
           factorsum=factorsum+list.get(x);
         }
         mult++;
       }

       if(factorsum == list.get(x)){ //testing to see if it's perfect
         perfectCount++;
       }
     }
     return perfectCount;
  }

  public String toString( ){





    return "Number of Odds:"+oddCount+"/n Number of Evens:"+evenCount+"/n Number of Perfects:"+perfectCount+list;
  }
}
```

Overall I just want the constructor to instantiate the ArrayList with the numbers from the runner.

Comment: Do you have to start with your numbers in a string? Could you start with them as a sequence of numbers, eg. `test = new NumAnalyzer(5, 12, 9, 6, 1, 4, 8, 6);`?

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor, you can split the word using spaces and then convert each token to an integer and finally collect to a list:-

```
list = Arrays.stream(word.split("\\s+"))
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Update**

For numbers instead of just integers, you can use this mapping:-

```
.map(s -> s.contains(".") ? (Number) Double.parseDouble(s) : Integer.parseInt(s))
```

If you strictly want `ArrayList` as opposed to any list, you can collect it as:-

```
.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

But it's better to use varargs if you are not working with Strings.

Comment: Worth to mention, that this example will require a reference type change from `ArrayList`->`List` and will work only for `Integers` (though there is a `Number` type in OP).

Comment: @J-Alex OP should use `List` instead of `ArrayList` - code to interface, not class. I agree with you regarding numbers, I've updated the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a constructor with `String` if you're not willing to use it?

Varargs constructor will fit here well:

```
class NumAnalyzer {
    private List<Number> list;

    public NumAnalyzer(Number... numbers) {
        list = Arrays.asList(numbers);
    }
}

void setup() {
    NumAnalyzer test = new NumAnalyzer(5, 12, 9, 6, 1, 4, 8, 6);
}
```

Pay attention that it's much better design desicition to use `private List<Number> list` instead of `private ArrayList<Number> list`.

Moreover, this code will not compile because you're treating `Numbers` as `Integers`. If you're really expecting any type of number, passing them as a `String` will require more granular parsing.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can remove all white spaces using replaceAll method and regexp or „ „.
2. Then, you can iterate over string chars and try to parse them into number.
3. After that, just add it to list of numbers.

However, You need to consider what happen if number has more than 1 digit

Comment: That's why @Kartik's method is the best. It will work for as many numbers as the user would like.

Comment: Sure, you are right :) But the question is does Toby understand streams :)